# Parse args to json elements in python

Tags: python, json, args

i have a data structure that i want to fill with cmd args

```
params = {
  ...
  ...
  "blockX": "{\"nameX\":["\Arg1\","\Arg2\",\"Arg3\"........"\ArgX\"]}",
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then i run a post request with the params as data:

```
r = requests.post("https://url", data=params)
```

I only know how to do it with one element

```
"BlockX": "{\"nameX\": \"%s\"}" %ArgX,
```

Regards

Comment: Is the value of 'blockX' purposely a string representation of a string? I.e., do you want the JSON to read `"blockX": {"name": [Arg1, Arg2, Arg3]}` or  `"blockX": '{"name": ["Arg1", "Arg2", "Arg3"]}'`?

Comment: good question...is the second option...with quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example suggest you want to `join` the arguments. You can convert any list into a single string by merging with a separator:

```
args = ['foo', 'bar', 'hold the mustard']
print('", "'.join(args))
```

So to get your list `'"Arg1", "Arg2"'` etc, join them with the '", "' separator and insert *that* into your template:

```
'{"nameX": ["%s"]}' % '", "'.join(args)
```

Note how `'` allows you to skip escaping each `"`. In your example, this would look like:

```
params = {
  #...
  "blockX": '{"nameX": ["%s"]}' % '", "'.join(args),
  # ...
 }
```

Please keep in mind that you are putting a string representation of a JSON into a JSON! This is... perhaps not the right thing to do. A proper API would expect just a single JSON, in which case you can dump `args` directly.

```
params = {
  #...
  "blockX": {
    "nameX": args
  },
  # ...
 }
```

Comment: @oso_togari What first argument?

Comment: i launch the program in cmd....the first arg is the name of the program itself, i need in the join, all except that...python c:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py -n -r ListaPrecios_AZ.py 9788420740164      i dont want ListaPrecios_AZ.py in the join

Comment: excuse me Mister...i forgot to say that i cannot use .join(args), because python throw me and error (args is not defined)    so i have to use sys.argv instead.

Comment: @oso_togari Then just remove it from the list. You can preface my code with `args = sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your arguments in `args` list, then you can try this:

```
import json
params['blockX'] = json.dumps({'nameX': args})
```

Comment: (note than there are other elements in params apart from blockX).... i have  to convert all the other elements in "param" to do the dump, or i can convert only blockX and then "insert" into params?

Comment: At first you need to convert what you need to convert to JSON (`blockX` in your example). Then you add that JSON to `params`.